# Add folder to Jenkins java.library.path for specific project

Tags: jenkins, java.library.path

I am trying to load a .so file (native library) in my Jenkins build. I believe the native libraries are all read via the java.library.path.  Can I add to the path just for a specific Jenkins project?

Answer (score 1):

Found the answer - you can edit the java command line parameters in the Jenkins setup. Just added -Djava.library.path= into the parameters.